# cornerRadius of UIImageView not working

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I had set cornerRadius like below:

```
@IBDesignable class CornerImageView: UIImageView {
@IBInspectable var cornerRadiusValue: CGFloat = 10.0 {
    didSet {
        setUpView()
    }
}
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    setUpView()
}
override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
    setUpView()
}

func setUpView() {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.cornerRadiusValue == -1 ? self.bounds.size.height/2 : self.cornerRadiusValue
    self.clipsToBounds = true
}
}
```

On storyboard, it worked correctly. But failed when run on device.
Please help!!!

[image: wrong cornerRadius]

[image: on Storyboard]

Comment: self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.size.width / 2

Comment: @Kuldeep height and width always  equals. I tried your code but it still wrong..

Comment: try to write your code on main thread.

Comment: assign cornerRadiusValue = -1 than check

Comment: @IOS i had set cornerRadiusValue = -1 on storyboard but when run on device, it work incorrect.

Comment: What is the frame of your imageview? Is if fixed width and height or proportional ? u should like self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.size.width / 2, self.layer.cornerRadius = self.cornerRadiusValue == -1 ? self.bounds.size.height/2 : self.cornerRadiusValue this condition gives radius as 10 only.

Comment: @Kuldeep when i call function setupView on main thread, it work like charm. Thanks you so much ^^

Comment: @NguyenvanDuc try this `(self.cornerRadiusValue == -1 ? self.bounds.size.height : self.cornerRadiusValue) / 2`

Comment: If you give image height with constraints fix then it will work perfect but if you give constraints as ratio so image height width is increase based on device at that time this issue occured, please cross check constraints also.

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
func setUpView() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.width/2;
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :

Set the image view height and width same or set the accept ratio to 1:1.

And put this code

```
imageview.layer.cornerRadius = imageview.frame.size.width / 2
imageview.clipsToBounds = true
```

It may helps you.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Actual frame of the Image will be set in viewDidAppear or LayouSubviews.
Just add the following Code.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    setUpView()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set corner radius half of the height of the `UIImageView` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method.

Comment: Why would you do this in a view controller's `viewDidLayoutSubview`? Why not put the code in the custom view class where it belongs?

Comment: In the custom view class method would be this layoutSubviews().